# How to invoke JTable action from outside JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, copy-paste

I have the `JTable` with `TransferHandler` which allows **copy-cut-paste** actions via **hotkeys** or **DnD**. I have the 3 `JButtons` (**copy-cut-paste**) outside of `JTable`, which should invoke the similar actions on `JTable's TransferHandler` (such as `canImport()` etc).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone, but I found the answer by myself while waiting for the answers:

```
private void onAction(String actionStr) {
    Action action = table.getActionMap().get(actionStr);
    ActionEvent newAE = new ActionEvent(table, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFOMED, actionStr);
    action.actionPerfomed(newAE);
}

private void decorateButtons() {
    copyButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent ae) {
            onAction("copy");
        }
    });
    cutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent ae) {
            onAction("cut");
        }
    });
    pasteButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent ae) {
            onAction("paste");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically a very similar approach as in a [recent question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17575003/203657): find the table's copy action in its actionMap, wrap it into a custom action that delegates to the original and use the custom action in the button:

```
table.setDragEnabled(true);
final Action copy = table.getActionMap().get("copy");
Action copyWithButton = new AbstractAction("copy") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        copy.actionPerformed(
                new ActionEvent(table, e.getID(), e.getActionCommand()));
    }
};
frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
frame.add(new JButton(copyWithButton), BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(5, 20)), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```